# Printing inside a method in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, pytest

I would like to print something inside the method. But the following code does not anything. But if I return the values I am able to print it outside the class. Why is it so? Any guidance would be great !

My code:

```
import pytest


class Test:

    def __init__(self, val_1, val_2):
        self.val_1 = val_1
        self.val_2 = val_2
        self.sum = 0
        self.mul = 0


    def sum_mul(self):
        self.sum = self.val_1 + self.val_2
        self.mul = self.val_1 * self.val_2

    def ret_val(self):
        return self.sum, self.mul 

    def test_exception(self,exception):
        raise exception
        return str(exception)

class Assert_Values:

    def __init__(self, number, val_1, val_2, exception):
        self.number = number
        self.val_1 = val_1
        self.val_2 = val_2
        self.exception = exception
        self.test_obj = Test(self.val_1, self.val_2)

    def execute_test(self):
        if self.number == 1:
            self.test_obj.sum_mul()
            self.val = self.test_obj.ret_val()
            assert self.val == (self.val_1 + self.val_2, self.val_1 * self.val_2)
            print (self.val)

        elif self.number == 2:
            with pytest.raises(self.exception):
                self.exception_val = self.test_obj.test_exception(self.exception)
                print (self.exception_val)
        else:
            print ("! Number not valid %d please enter another number" % (self.number))

assert_values = Assert_Values(2,4,5,ValueError)
assert_values.execute_test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pytest [captures stdout](http://pytest.org/latest/capture.html); `print()` writes to `stdout` and you'll *only* see the output if there is a test failure.

Use the `-s` flag if you want to see `stdout` output instead:

```
py.test -s
```